# How to write sql 'like' statement in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

How would you write the following query in Laravel style?

```
SELECT * FROM `job_details` WHERE `job_title` LIKE '%officer%' AND `category_id` = 1 AND `city_id` = 1
```

I tried something below but it does not work:

```
DB::(job_details)->where(job_title LIKE '%officer%')->and(category_id=1)->and(city_id=1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
DB::table('job_details')->where('job_title', 'like', '%officer%')
                      ->where('category_id', 1)
                      ->where('city_id', 1)
                      ->get();
```

Comment: I am trying to fetch the data but it is showing blank page..this is my code:

Comment: $check = DB::table('job_details')->where('job_title', 'like', '%$keyword%')
                      ->where('category_id', $category_id)
                      ->where('city_id', $city_id)->get();
        
        foreach($check as $result)
        {
            echo $result->job_title."<br>";
        }

Comment: What's the result of `dd($check)`? Probably it is empty.

Comment: yes it shows emply..but i have jobs with title 'officer'..it is supposed to show me the result

Comment: Ok I got the problem. I am using a variable name between %% signs..like where('job_title', 'like', '%$title%')..if I remove the variable then it works fine..like where('job_title', 'like', '%officer%')

Comment: Do it like this `where('job_title', 'like', '%'.$title.'%')` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('name', 'like', 'T%')
                ->get();
```

in your case try like this :

```
  DB::table('job_details')
          ->where([
            ['job_title', 'like', '%officer%'],
            ['category_id', '=', 1], 
            ['city_id', '=', 1]
                 ])->get();
```

refer : [laravel where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)